# Directed closed loop inside a matrix

Tags: matrices

The matrix below pops up in the Kac-Ward solution of the 2D Ising model.
[image: kac-ward]

Writing down the matrix elements is trivial. However, I have never drawn a directed closed loop inside a matrix. Can anyone make some comments on how to draw it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `nicematrix`. The hardest part is getting the arrows on every segment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, arrows.meta, decorations.markings}

\tikzset{arrow every segment/.style={
    decoration={
        show path construction, 
            lineto code={\path[decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .6 with {\arrow{Latex}}}] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            }
    }, postaction={decorate}
}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[cell-space-limits=1.25ex]
    1 & \gamma\tanh(\beta) & \cdot & \cdot\\
    \cdot & 1 & \cdot & \gamma\tanh(\beta)\\
    \gamma\tanh(\beta) & \cdot & 1 & \cdot\\
    \cdot & \cdot & \gamma\tanh(\beta) & 1
\CodeAfter
    \tikz
    \draw[semithick, cyan, arrow every segment, line join=round, line cap=round] (1.5-|1.5)--(3.5-|1.5)--(3.5-|3.5)
        --(4.5-|3.5)--(4.5-|4.5)--(2.5-|4.5)--(2.5-|2.5)
        --(1.5-|2.5)--(1.5-|1.5);
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```